# What is the keycode for Clear and Equal on the Numpad on Mac?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, standards

**I need to know what the keycode is for the clear and the equal key on the numpad.**

[image]

I've seen different sources explain it, but they all say something different. Can someone give me a definite answer?

**Update:**

I get the keycodes this way:

```
NSEvent *result = incomingEvent;
unichar key = result.keyCode;
```

Which makes the equal sign on the numpad to be 81 and the normal equal sign to be 24.

How do I get the keycodes you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/Headers/Events.h
```

contains constants for virtual keycodes, in particular

```
kVK_ANSI_Equal                = 0x18
kVK_ANSI_KeypadClear          = 0x47
kVK_ANSI_KeypadEquals         = 0x51
```

Since the code for the equal sign is the same that you obtained from `NSEvent` these definitions seem to be what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn't add up with my experience. I've asked a little follow up question above.

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk: You said that you got 81 for the equal sign on the numerical keypad. 81 is 0x51 in hexadecimal notation, so that matches exactly.

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk: The keycode for the "normal" equal sign matches also your experience: 0x18 = 24, I have added that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and competent help :-). It worked.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.asquare.net/javascript/tests/KeyCode.html), 12 for clear and 187 for equal.

Comment: That's just not the case. I get the keycode by doing this: NSEvent *result = incomingEvent;
        unichar key = result.keyCode; It seems like the equal sign on the keypad was 81, but I still don't have any idea about the clear sign.

Answer (score 0):

Since macOS Sierra 10.12, `keyCode` has been according to the [Universal Serial Bus HID Usage Tables](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf) (go to section: 10 Keyboard/Keypad Page, page 51).

The keyCodes in HEX are:

```
keyPad Clear = 0x53
keyPad Equal = 0x67
```

The rest of the keyCodes are:

```
Usage           Usage ID (hex)
Keyboard a and A        0x04
Keyboard b and B        0x05
Keyboard c and C        0x06
Keyboard d and D        0x07
Keyboard e and E        0x08
Keyboard f and F        0x09
Keyboard g and G        0x0A
Keyboard h and H        0x0B
Keyboard i and I        0x0C
Keyboard j and J        0x0D
Keyboard k and K        0x0E
Keyboard l and L        0x0F
Keyboard m and M        0x10
Keyboard n and N        0x11
Keyboard o and O        0x12
Keyboard p and P        0x13
Keyboard q and Q        0x14
Keyboard r and R        0x15
Keyboard s and S        0x16
Keyboard t and T        0x17
Keyboard u and U        0x18
Keyboard v and V        0x19
Keyboard w and W        0x1A
Keyboard x and X        0x1B
Keyboard y and Y        0x1C
Keyboard z and Z        0x1D
Keyboard 1 and !        0x1E
Keyboard 2 and @        0x1F
Keyboard 3 and #        0x20
Keyboard 4 and $        0x21
Keyboard 5 and %        0x22
Keyboard 6 and ^        0x23
Keyboard 7 and &        0x24
Keyboard 8 and *        0x25
Keyboard 9 and (        0x26
Keyboard 0 and )        0x27
Keyboard Return (Enter) 0x28
Keyboard Escape         0x29
Keyboard Delete (Backspace)0x2A
Keyboard Tab            0x2B
Keyboard Spacebar       0x2C
Keyboard - and _        0x2D
Keyboard = and +        0x2E
Keyboard [ and {        0x2F
Keyboard ] and }        0x30
Keyboard \ and |        0x31
Keyboard Non-US # and ~ 0x32
Keyboard ; and :        0x33
Keyboard ' and "        0x34
Keyboard Grave Accent and Tilde 0x35
Keyboard , and "<"      0x36
Keyboard . and ">"      0x37
Keyboard / and ?        0x38
Keyboard Caps Lock      0x39
Keyboard F1             0x3A
Keyboard F2             0x3B
Keyboard F3             0x3C
Keyboard F4             0x3D
Keyboard F5             0x3E
Keyboard F6             0x3F
Keyboard F7             0x40
Keyboard F8             0x41
Keyboard F9             0x42
Keyboard F10            0x43
Keyboard F11            0x44
Keyboard F12            0x45
Keyboard Print Screen   0x46
Keyboard Scroll Lock    0x47
Keyboard Pause          0x48
Keyboard Insert         0x49
Keyboard Home           0x4A
Keyboard Page Up        0x4B
Keyboard Delete Forward 0x4C
Keyboard End            0x4D
Keyboard Page Down      0x4E
Keyboard Right Arrow    0x4F
Keyboard Left Arrow     0x50
Keyboard Down Arrow     0x51
Keyboard Up Arrow       0x52
Keypad Num Lock and Clear   0x53
Keypad /                0x54
Keypad *                0x55
Keypad -                0x56
Keypad +                0x57
Keypad Enter            0x58
Keypad 1 and End        0x59
Keypad 2 and Down Arrow 0x5A
Keypad 3 and Page Down  0x5B
Keypad 4 and Left Arrow 0x5C
Keypad 5                0x5D
Keypad 6 and Right Arrow    0x5E
Keypad 7 and Home       0x5F
Keypad 8 and Up Arrow   0x60
Keypad 9 and Page Up    0x61
Keypad 0 and Insert     0x62
Keypad . and Delete     0x63
Keyboard Non-US \ and | 0x64
Keyboard Application    0x65
Keyboard Power          0x66
Keypad =                0x67
Keyboard F13            0x68
Keyboard F14            0x69
Keyboard F15            0x6A
Keyboard F16            0x6B
Keyboard F17            0x6C
Keyboard F18            0x6D
Keyboard F19            0x6E
Keyboard F20            0x6F
Keyboard F21            0x70
Keyboard F22            0x71
Keyboard F23            0x72
Keyboard F24            0x73
Keyboard Left Control   0xE0
Keyboard Left Shift     0xE1
Keyboard Left Alt       0xE2
Keyboard Left GUI       0xE3
Keyboard Right Control  0xE4
Keyboard Right Shift    0xE5
Keyboard Right Alt      0xE6
Keyboard Right GUI      0xE7
```